# Como pegar o numero separado pela função inteiro logo abaixo e ordena-lo corretamente como descrito na duvida principal em negrito na pergunta no C++

Tags: c++

A função para separar um numero inteiro de um não inteiro é simples

```
void Inteiro(float n)
 {
      int x = n;
      float y = n;
      if (x==y)
      {
        cout << "E inteiro" << endl;
      }
      else 
      {
        cout << "Nao e inteiro" << endl;
       }
}
```

só que eu queria que fizesse algo assim:
exemplo de entrada de dados OBS: dados estão num arquivo `txt`

```
0,9
36646
0,4
38833
33882
38849
0,7
36646
```

**duvida principal, é algoritmo disso que preciso nessa questão**
*{Preciso da lógica que deve ser implementada na função inteiro que faça leitura de modo 0,9 é nota correspondente ao número de baixo que no caso 36646 um inteiro, logo seguida vem 0,4 que dizer novo numero quebrado em que corresponde os número 38833,33882,38849 e 0,7 corresponde novamente o número 36646 só que 0,7 deverá ser somado com 0,9 porque ambos é do mesmo número*}

e quando mandar imprimir vai mostrar o número com sua nota correspondente

como

```
36646 1,6 //com a nota somada
....
..
.
.
```

Comment: Não esta clara qual é a sua dúvida. Seu título faz uma pergunta que você mesmo responde. Depois você menciona uma outra definição de problema mas sem código nem dúvida. Seria melhor você editar sua pergunta para deixar claro qual o problema que você esta tendo e a solução que você esta tentando.

Comment: @TiagoGomes de uma olhada na edição vê se entende, foco na parte em negrito no trecho em itálico da pergunta.

Comment: Rodolfo, na "parte em negrito" você pede o algoritmo, e acho difícil que alguém o faça por você. O objetivo do site é responder a dúvidas concretas e objetivas, e não fazer a sua lição de casa por você. Porque não edita a pergunta e foca em uma dúvida específica (por exemplo, como realmente identificar se um número é inteiro ou não? ou, como armazenar e acessar um valor mapeado por uma chave? - no seu caso, o ID da matrícula - e etc). Facilita que você obtenha uma resposta, e depois você pode abrir novas perguntas para outras dúvidas que tiver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não está claro na pergunta, mas parece que a sua dificuldade é como relacionar pares de valores (a matrícula do aluno e a sua nota, por exemplo, ou a pontuação de um jogador ao seu ID, etc).

Para isso, use [um mapa (classe `map`)](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/) da biblioteca padrão. O código abaixo exemplifica seu uso no contexto do seu problema (sem o restante da leitura do arquivo e identificação dos números):

```
#include <string>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    /* Define o mapa de notas (matrícula x valor da nota). */
    map<int, float> notas;

    notas[36646] += 0.9f;

    notas[38833] += 0.4f;
    notas[33882] += 0.4f;
    notas[38849] += 0.4f;

    notas[36646] += 0.7f; /* <- Observe a repetição da matricula 36646! */


    /* Teste de verificação */

    map<int, float>::iterator it;
    for(it = notas.begin(); it != notas.end(); ++it)
    {
        printf("Matricula #%d -> Nota: %02.02f\n", it->first, it->second);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Observações:

1. O mapa é declarado como `map<int, float>` porque ele relaciona um inteiro (a matrícula) com um valor de ponto flutuante (a nota). Assim, sempre que fizer `nota[XXXX]` você tem acesso ao valor da nota para a matrícula XXXX. Se esse valor ainda não foi atualizado no mapa, ele é zero (0).
2. As atualizações são sempre feitas usando o operador `+=` porque assim ele não substitui o valor que já estava mapeado para aquela matrícula, e sim soma o novo valor naquele que já existia.
3. Os valores de ponto flutuante fixo no meu código de exemplo são definidos com uma letra `f` ao final para indicar isso ao compilador e evitar avisos chatos. No seu caso você irá ler do arquivo então essa letra não irá aparecer.
4. O pedaço de código no final com o laço `for` serve apenas para demonstrar que o resultado é o que você espera.

Saída do programa de exemplo anterior:

```
Matricula #33882 -> Nota: 0.40
Matricula #36646 -> Nota: 1.60
Matricula #38833 -> Nota: 0.40
Matricula #38849 -> Nota: 0.40
```